# Почему пункты списка онтопик-тем не пронумерованы?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, справка, тематика

я задал вопрос:
[Как сконфигурировать ноубук с WiFi как точку доступа (чтобы он этот WiFi раздавал в полевых условиях)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455742/)

мне ответили, что топик тут:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

я считаю, что мой вопрос онтопик (пункт "к настройке физических, ... серверов-приложений, серверов баз данных, веб-серверов").

встречный вопрос о праве собственности на ноутбук (мой ли он лично, или выдан организаций) считаю невозможным к ответу, в связи с тем, что подписывал NDA, кроме того, знание этого факта не важно для ответа по существу.

И такие баталии по каждому вопросу. Доколе?

Проблема в том, что мне трудно сослаться на конкретный пункт, так как они не пронумерованы.

Comment: Проще пойти и купить профессиональную внешнюю точку доступа с нормальной антенной с дальностью километров в 7 и крепежом, чем пытаться ноутбук переделывать в неё. Она еще и стоит дешевле раза в 2 чем ноутбук, там тот же linux внутри, плюс есть интерфейс для настройки от производителя. Зачем страдать, делать велосипеды и еще при этом плодить бессмысленные треды в мете?

Comment: ну вы же написали этот ответ тут, а не там. Значит понимаете, что там этот ответ оффтопик, потому что отвечает на другой вопрос. (на вопрос "как организовать связь на 7 километров", что мне совсем не надо). Я не написал что это мне не надо, потому что я не могу расписать все действия, которые я не собираюсь выполнять. Ну правда, не писать же мне в тексте вопроса "а вот антена мне не нужна".

Comment: Мне кажется, что ваш вопрос вполне может быть по теме, если уточнить подробности. А вот тон общения рекомендую поменять. )

Comment: Я не вижу, как этот вопрос можно уточнить. Если бы я знал ответ, я писал бы не вопрос, а сразу ответ на аналогичный вопрос. Это же относится и к другим комментаторам - не знают как надо, но лезут с запросами "ты расскажи по-подробнее"

Answer (score 1):

> И такие баталии по каждому вопросу. Доколе?

Такие баталии только с вами. Вы срываетесь на оскорбления в обсуждениях по каждому вопросу. Зачем?

- Вы хотите переделать правила сообщества? Для этого нужно сначала приобрести хоть какой-то опыт и сделать что-то полезное для SO.
- Вам просто нравится скандалить? Сожалею, но мы вам не можем предоставить такой возможности. Не здесь.
- Хотите доказать, что вы дартаньян, а остальные - вахтеры? Бесполезно.

Что касается правил - да мы можем хоть каждую строку пронумеровать, как в священном писании, и потом ссылаться на них. Процитирую вам "Скандалистам, абзац 4, стих 9, 12-13":

> Будьте дружелюбными, терпеливыми и доброжелательными... Если вы обращаетесь за помощью, постарайтесь, чтобы другим пользователям было как можно проще вам помочь. В сообществе все делается добровольно, не стоит ждать ответа на требования о помощи.

Будет ли толк в номерах, если вы используете только ту часть правил, которая вам удобна, а остальными пренебрегаете?

Comment: не зачем, а почему. Потому что мне стараются доказать, что единственный правильный ответ я могу найти и сам. Действительно могу, потратив пару месяцев.

Comment: @hse5yzdx: спокойно объясните свою точку зрения. Вас же не оскорбляют.

Comment: а я не согласен, что не оскорбляют. Например я считаю, что вопрос о том, кого я считаю админами - это оскорбление.

Comment: @hse5yzdx судя по переписке, любой вопрос, который вам задают - оскорбление. включая устойчивое выражение "если я правильно понял вопрос" в [ответе Виктора](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455762/177221) - даже на него в ответ вы язвите. на всякий случай - это не вопрос. просто комментарий.

Comment: @hse5yzdx по делу - если вы считаете что вас что-то оскорбляет - ставьте тревогу. а не начинайте оскорблять в ответ.

Comment: я не язвлю, а задаю уточняющий вопрос. Мне действительно неясно, как мой вопрос можно понять неправильно.